# How to eliminate the lag on my UI when loading more items on my grid view?

Tags: android, gridview, lazy-loading, lag, onscrolllistener

Please help me with my problem about grid view. Currently I am developing a gallery app where grid view of images is shown. Now, the problem is every time that I load more items on my grid view by triggering my on scroll method, the UI lags for certain amount of time before displaying the newly loaded items. I just want to fix the lag or you can suggest some ideas or trick that will improve my grid view. And maybe, if possible, you can give me an idea on how to put a progress bar at the bottom of the grid view that will be shown when the adding of grid view items is started and will disappear after adding of grid view items is done.

These are codes:

This is the main activity where the on scroll method is implemented, when on scroll method is triggered and if the condition is fulfilled, it will call the Utils' GenerateData inner class that extends AsyncTask and return a array list and this array list will be added to the array on the main activity.

GridViewActivity:

```
public class GridViewActivity extends Activity implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener, AbsListView.OnItemClickListener{
    private GridView gridView;
    private GridViewImageAdapter adapter;
    private Utils utils;
    private GenerateData generateData;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> galleryAttributes;
    private int columnWidth;
    private int urlPageIndex = 1;
    private boolean hasRequestedMore;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_grid_view);

        setTitle("Gallery");

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
        utils = new Utils(this);
        InitializeGridLayout();

        galleryAttributes = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        generateData = utils.new GenerateData(urlPageIndex);
        try {
            galleryAttributes.addAll(generateData.execute().get());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        adapter = new GridViewImageAdapter(GridViewActivity.this, galleryAttributes , columnWidth);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        gridView.setOnScrollListener(this);
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }

    public void InitializeGridLayout() { 
        Resources r = getResources();
        float padding = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,AppConstant.GRID_PADDING, r.getDisplayMetrics());
        columnWidth = (int) ((utils.getScreenWidth() - ((AppConstant.NUM_OF_COLUMNS + 1) * padding)) / AppConstant.NUM_OF_COLUMNS);
        gridView.setNumColumns(AppConstant.NUM_OF_COLUMNS);
        gridView.setColumnWidth(columnWidth);
        gridView.setStretchMode(GridView.NO_STRETCH);
        gridView.setPadding((int) padding, (int) padding, (int) padding,(int) padding);
        gridView.setHorizontalSpacing((int) padding);
        gridView.setVerticalSpacing((int) padding);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(GridViewActivity.this,
                CarouselViewActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("position", position);
        intent.putExtra("galleryAttributes", galleryAttributes);
        startActivity(intent);
        Log.e("onItemClick: ", "" + position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("onScrollStateChanged: ", "" + scrollState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("onScroll: ", "firstVisibleItem:" + firstVisibleItem
                + " visibleItemCount:" + visibleItemCount + " totalItemCount:"
                + totalItemCount);
        if (!hasRequestedMore) {
            int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
            if (lastInScreen >= totalItemCount) {
                hasRequestedMore = true;
                onLoadMoreItems();
            }
        }
    }

    public void onLoadMoreItems() {
        if (urlPageIndex < 3) {
            urlPageIndex++;
            generateData = utils.new GenerateData(urlPageIndex);
            try {
                galleryAttributes.addAll(generateData.execute().get());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            hasRequestedMore = false;
        }
    }
```

}

This is my Utils class, this class is the responsible for retrieving data from Json and putting it on an array list that will be return from its caller.

Utils:

```
public class Utils {

    private Context context;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public Utils(){}

    public Utils(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    public class GenerateData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>{
        private JSONArray dataJsonArr;
        private JsonParser jParser;
        private JSONObject json;
        private JSONObject c;
        private HashMap<String, String> map;
        private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> galleryAttributes;
        private int urlPageIndex;
        private GridViewImageAdapter gridViewAdapter;
        private boolean onLoadMore = false;

        public GenerateData(int urlPageIndex){
            this.urlPageIndex = urlPageIndex;
            new InitializeJsonArray().execute();
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(
                Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try{
                for(int i = 0; i< dataJsonArr.length(); i++)
                {
                    c = dataJsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
                    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put("Link", c.getString("Link"));
                    galleryAttributes.add(map);
                }
            }

            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
            return galleryAttributes;
        }

        public class InitializeJsonArray extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{ 
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dataJsonArr = null;
                jParser = new JsonParser();
                json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(AppConstant.JSON_URL+urlPageIndex);
                try {
                    dataJsonArr = json.getJSONArray(AppConstant.JSON_ARRAY_NAME);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                galleryAttributes = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                galleryAttributes.ensureCapacity(dataJsonArr.length());
                return null;
            }   
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi") public int getScreenWidth() {
        int columnWidth;
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

        final Point point = new Point();
        try {
            display.getSize(point);
        } catch (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError ignore) {
            point.x = display.getWidth();
            point.y = display.getHeight();
        }
        columnWidth = point.x;
        return columnWidth;
    }
}
```

And finally my GridViewImageAdapter class:

```
public class GridViewImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context context;
    private int imageWidth;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> galleryAttributes;
    ImageView imageView;

    public GridViewImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> galleryAttributes, int imageWidth){
        this.galleryAttributes = galleryAttributes;
        this.context = context;
        this.imageWidth = imageWidth;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return galleryAttributes.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return galleryAttributes.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(context);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        Picasso.with(context).load(galleryAttributes.get(position).get("Link")).placeholder(R.drawable.loadingimage).into(imageView);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(imageWidth,imageWidth));
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Everytime you are creating this object. You could create it on constructor and put the object here. Not a much improver, but it does :-/

Comment: @Panther can you specify what object is that?

Comment: Also take a look at this and optimize your images `http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html`

Comment: @Panther, I already used Picasso frame for loading url images into my imageviews

Comment: hey, nowhere in picaso i see it optimizing images for the `imageview` size, you should atleast try `.resize(x,y)` in the `Picasso` to reduce the memory usage for Bitmaps

Comment: still don't work. Picasso can adjust the image to grid view' s params